# MySQL statement for group_concat in Update from two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sql-update

I have 3 tables below I'm trying to write a `group_concat` statement for the "item" column in the table cart_session

TABLE `products`

```
id      name
------------------------
123  |  car
456  |  boat
789  |  house

--------------------------------
```

TABLE `cart_items`

```
pid session
----------------------
123  |  ABCD    
456  |  ABCD
789  |  EFGH

----------------------------------
```

TABLE `cart_session`

```
id   item
----------------------------
ABCD  |  car,boat
EFGH  |  house
```

Comment: Don't do this. See normalisation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the update/join syntax as follows:

```
update cart_session cs
inner join (
    select ci.session, group_concat(p.name) item
    from products p
    inner join cart_items ci on ci.pid = p.pid
    group by ci.session
) x on x.session = cs.session
set cs.item = x.item
```

Another option uses a correlated subquery:

```
update cart_session cs
set cs.item = (
    select group_concat(p.name)
    from products p
    inner join cart_items ci on ci.pid = p.pid
    where ci.session = cs.session
)
```

This is slightly different: this query would assign a `null` value to rows in `cart_session` that have no match in the other tables, while the first query leaves such rows intact.